# How to configure xorg.conf for widescreen VNC on headless Linux/Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, x11, vnc, xorg

I have a Ubuntu 12.10 Box configured to run headless. I've managed to boot X headless by a lot of trial and error but I still have a glitch:
When booting using the monitor, it all works ok, widescreen resolution and all, when booting headless it will stick with 4:3 resolutions, I suspect that it has something to do with the vesa driver.

Specs:

- video card intel HD 4000 (i7 integrated)
- ubuntu 12.10 (latest updates)

here is my /etc/X11/`xorg.conf`:

```
Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "NoAccel"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "AccelMethod"           # <str>
        #Option     "Backlight"             # <str>
        #Option     "DRI"                   # <str>
        #Option     "ColorKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "VideoKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "Tiling"                # [<bool>]
        #Option     "LinearFramebuffer"     # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SwapbuffersWait"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "TripleBuffer"          # [<bool>]
        #Option     "XvPreferOverlay"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HotPlug"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "RelaxedFencing"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "XvMC"                  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
        #Option     "TearFree"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "PerCrtcPixmaps"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "FallbackDebug"         # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DebugFlushBatches"     # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DebugFlushCaches"      # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DebugWait"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "BufferCache"           # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "intelCard"
    Driver      "intel"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0" 
    Option      "ConnectedMonitor" "SME2220NW"
    Option      "CustomEDID" "SME2220NW:/etc/X11/samsung.edid"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "SME2220NW"
    VendorName "SAM"
    ModelName "SME2220NW"
    # Block type: 2:0 3:fd
    HorizSync 30-81
    VertRefresh 56-75
    # Max dot clock (video bandwidth) 150 MHz
    # Block type: 2:0 3:fc
    # Block type: 2:0 3:ff
    # DPMS capabilities: Active off:yes  Suspend:no  Standby:no

    Mode    "1680x1050" # vfreq 59.883Hz, hfreq 64.674kHz
        DotClock    119.000000
        HTimings    1680 1728 1760 1840
        VTimings    1050 1053 1059 1080
        Flags   "-HSync" "+VSync"
    EndMode  

    Option   "enable" "true"
    Option   "Preferred Mode" "1680x1050"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "SME2220NW"
    Device      "intelCard"
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "1680x1050 +0+0; 1440x900 +0+0; 1280x1024 +0+0; 1280x960 +0+0; 1280x800 +0+0; 1024x768 +0+0; 800x600 +0+0; 640x480 +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

here is my /var/log/`xorg.0.log`:

```
[  8841.997] 
X.Org X Server 1.13.1.901 (1.13.2 RC 1)
Release Date: 2013-01-03
[  8841.997] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  8841.997] Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.24-32-xen x86_64 Ubuntu
[  8841.997] Current Operating System: Linux L2 3.7.0-7-generic #15-Ubuntu SMP Sat Dec 15 16:34:25 UTC 2012 x86_64
[  8841.997] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.7.0-7-generic root=UUID=58d10bfd-8c7c-4308-98eb-7002337b7510 ro nomodeset
[  8841.997] Build Date: 04 January 2013  11:17:34AM
[  8841.997] xorg-server 2:1.13.1.901+git20130104+server-1.13-branch.3a8c618a-0ubuntu0ricotz~quantal (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[  8841.997] Current version of pixman: 0.28.2
[  8841.997]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  8841.997] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  8841.997] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Jan 30 12:23:13 2013
[  8841.997] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[  8841.997] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  8841.998] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[  8841.998] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen" (0)
[  8841.998] (**) |   |-->Monitor "SME2220NW"
[  8841.998] (**) |   |-->Device "intelCard"
[  8841.998] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  8841.998] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  8841.998] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[  8841.998] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[  8841.998]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  8841.998] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[  8841.998]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  8841.998] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[  8841.998]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  8841.998] (WW) The directory "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType" does not exist.
[  8841.998]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  8841.998] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    built-ins
[  8841.998] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  8841.998] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[  8841.998] (II) Loader magic: 0x7ff68004ac40
[  8841.998] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  8841.998]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  8841.998]    X.Org Video Driver: 13.1
[  8841.998]    X.Org XInput driver : 18.0
[  8841.998]    X.Org Server Extension : 7.0
[  8841.999] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0162:1043:84ca rev 9, Mem @ 0xf7800000/4194304, 0xe0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64
[  8841.999] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[  8841.999] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[  8841.999] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  8842.000] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  8842.000] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  8842.000]    compiled for 1.13.1.901, module version = 1.0.0
[  8842.000]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 7.0
[  8842.000] (==) AIGLX enabled
[  8842.000] Loading extension GLX
[  8842.000] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[  8842.000] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[  8842.000] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  8842.000]    compiled for 1.13.1.901, module version = 2.20.19
[  8842.000]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  8842.000]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.1
[  8842.000] (II) intel: Driver for Intel Integrated Graphics Chipsets: i810,
    i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G, 915G,
    E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM, Pineview G,
    965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33, GM45,
    4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43, B43, Clarkdale, Arrandale,
    Sandybridge Desktop (GT1), Sandybridge Desktop (GT2),
    Sandybridge Desktop (GT2+), Sandybridge Mobile (GT1),
    Sandybridge Mobile (GT2), Sandybridge Mobile (GT2+),
    Sandybridge Server, Ivybridge Mobile (GT1), Ivybridge Mobile (GT2),
    Ivybridge Desktop (GT1), Ivybridge Desktop (GT2), Ivybridge Server,
    Ivybridge Server (GT2), Haswell Desktop (GT1), Haswell Desktop (GT2),
    Haswell Desktop (GT2+), Haswell Mobile (GT1), Haswell Mobile (GT2),
    Haswell Mobile (GT2+), Haswell Server (GT1), Haswell Server (GT2),
    Haswell Server (GT2+), Haswell SDV Desktop (GT1),
    Haswell SDV Desktop (GT2), Haswell SDV Desktop (GT2+),
    Haswell SDV Mobile (GT1), Haswell SDV Mobile (GT2),
    Haswell SDV Mobile (GT2+), Haswell SDV Server (GT1),
    Haswell SDV Server (GT2), Haswell SDV Server (GT2+),
    Haswell ULT Desktop (GT1), Haswell ULT Desktop (GT2),
    Haswell ULT Desktop (GT2+), Haswell ULT Mobile (GT1),
    Haswell ULT Mobile (GT2), Haswell ULT Mobile (GT2+),
    Haswell ULT Server (GT1), Haswell ULT Server (GT2),
    Haswell ULT Server (GT2+), Haswell CRW Desktop (GT1),
    Haswell CRW Desktop (GT2), Haswell CRW Desktop (GT2+),
    Haswell CRW Mobile (GT1), Haswell CRW Mobile (GT2),
    Haswell CRW Mobile (GT2+), Haswell CRW Server (GT1),
    Haswell CRW Server (GT2), Haswell CRW Server (GT2+),
    ValleyView PO board
[  8842.001] (++) using VT number 7

[  8842.004] (EE) No devices detected.
[  8842.004] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[  8842.004] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 1
[  8842.004] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[  8842.004] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[  8842.004] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[  8842.004] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[  8842.004] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[  8842.004] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  8842.004]    compiled for 1.13.1.901, module version = 2.20.19
[  8842.004]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  8842.004]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.1
[  8842.004] (II) UnloadModule: "intel"
[  8842.004] (II) Unloading intel
[  8842.004] (II) Failed to load module "intel" (already loaded, 32758)
[  8842.004] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[  8842.005] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[  8842.005] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  8842.005]    compiled for 1.13.0, module version = 2.3.2
[  8842.005]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  8842.005]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.0
[  8842.005] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[  8842.005] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[  8842.005] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  8842.005]    compiled for 1.13.0, module version = 0.5.0
[  8842.005]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  8842.005]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.0
[  8842.005] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[  8842.005] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[  8842.005] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  8842.005]    compiled for 1.12.99.903, module version = 0.4.3
[  8842.005]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  8842.005]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.0
[  8842.005] (II) intel: Driver for Intel Integrated Graphics Chipsets: i810,
    i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G, 915G,
    E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM, Pineview G,
    965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33, GM45,
    4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43, B43, Clarkdale, Arrandale,
    Sandybridge Desktop (GT1), Sandybridge Desktop (GT2),
    Sandybridge Desktop (GT2+), Sandybridge Mobile (GT1),
    Sandybridge Mobile (GT2), Sandybridge Mobile (GT2+),
    Sandybridge Server, Ivybridge Mobile (GT1), Ivybridge Mobile (GT2),
    Ivybridge Desktop (GT1), Ivybridge Desktop (GT2), Ivybridge Server,
    Ivybridge Server (GT2), Haswell Desktop (GT1), Haswell Desktop (GT2),
    Haswell Desktop (GT2+), Haswell Mobile (GT1), Haswell Mobile (GT2),
    Haswell Mobile (GT2+), Haswell Server (GT1), Haswell Server (GT2),
    Haswell Server (GT2+), Haswell SDV Desktop (GT1),
    Haswell SDV Desktop (GT2), Haswell SDV Desktop (GT2+),
    Haswell SDV Mobile (GT1), Haswell SDV Mobile (GT2),
    Haswell SDV Mobile (GT2+), Haswell SDV Server (GT1),
    Haswell SDV Server (GT2), Haswell SDV Server (GT2+),
    Haswell ULT Desktop (GT1), Haswell ULT Desktop (GT2),
    Haswell ULT Desktop (GT2+), Haswell ULT Mobile (GT1),
    Haswell ULT Mobile (GT2), Haswell ULT Mobile (GT2+),
    Haswell ULT Server (GT1), Haswell ULT Server (GT2),
    Haswell ULT Server (GT2+), Haswell CRW Desktop (GT1),
    Haswell CRW Desktop (GT2), Haswell CRW Desktop (GT2+),
    Haswell CRW Mobile (GT1), Haswell CRW Mobile (GT2),
    Haswell CRW Mobile (GT2+), Haswell CRW Server (GT1),
    Haswell CRW Server (GT2), Haswell CRW Server (GT2+),
    ValleyView PO board
[  8842.006] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[  8842.006] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[  8842.006] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[  8842.006] (++) using VT number 7

[  8842.006] (WW) xf86OpenConsole: setpgid failed: Operation not permitted
[  8842.006] (WW) xf86OpenConsole: setsid failed: Operation not permitted
[  8842.008] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[  8842.008] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[  8842.008] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[  8842.008] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[  8842.008] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[  8842.008] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[  8842.008] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  8842.008]    compiled for 1.13.1.901, module version = 0.0.2
[  8842.008]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.1
[  8842.008] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[  8842.008] (II) Loading sub module "vbe"
[  8842.008] (II) LoadModule: "vbe"
[  8842.009] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvbe.so
[  8842.009] (II) Module vbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  8842.009]    compiled for 1.13.1.901, module version = 1.1.0
[  8842.009]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.1
[  8842.009] (II) Loading sub module "int10"
[  8842.009] (II) LoadModule: "int10"
[  8842.009] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libint10.so
[  8842.009] (II) Module int10: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  8842.009]    compiled for 1.13.1.901, module version = 1.0.0
[  8842.009]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.1
[  8842.009] (II) VESA(0): initializing int10
[  8842.009] (II) VESA(0): Primary V_BIOS segment is: 0xc000
[  8842.010] (II) VESA(0): VESA BIOS detected
[  8842.010] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Version 3.0
[  8842.010] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Total Mem: 262080 kB
[  8842.010] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM: Intel(R) Sandybridge/Ivybridge Graphics Chipset Accelerated VGA BIOS
[  8842.010] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Software Rev: 1.0
[  8842.010] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Vendor: Intel Corporation
[  8842.010] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product: Intel(R) Sandybridge/Ivybridge Graphics Controller
[  8842.010] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product Rev: Hardware Version 0.0
[  8842.023] (==) VESA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[  8842.023] (==) VESA(0): RGB weight 888
[  8842.023] (==) VESA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[  8842.023] (==) VESA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[  8842.023] (II) Loading sub module "ddc"
[  8842.023] (II) LoadModule: "ddc"
[  8842.023] (II) Module "ddc" already built-in
[  8842.029] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC supported
[  8842.029] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC Level none
[  8842.029] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC transfer in appr. 0 sec.
[  8842.030] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC read failed
[  8842.030] (II) VESA(0): Searching for matching VESA mode(s):
[  8842.030] Mode: 160 (0x0)
[  8842.030]    ModeAttributes: 0x0
[  8842.030]    WinAAttributes: 0x0
[  8842.030]    WinBAttributes: 0x0
...
[  8842.043] (II) VESA(0): Total Memory: 4095 64KB banks (262080kB)
[  8842.043] (II) VESA(0): SME2220NW: Using hsync range of 30.00-81.00 kHz
[  8842.043] (II) VESA(0): SME2220NW: Using vrefresh range of 56.00-75.00 Hz
[  8842.043] (WW) VESA(0): Unable to estimate virtual size
[  8842.043] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "1920x1440" (no mode of this name)
[  8842.043] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "1600x1200" (no mode of this name)
[  8842.043] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "1280x1024" (no mode of this name)
[  8842.043] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "1024x768" (no mode of this name)
[  8842.043] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "1024x768" (no mode of this name)
[  8842.043] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "800x600" (no mode of this name)
[  8842.043] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "640x480" (no mode of this name)
[  8842.043] (WW) VESA(0): No valid modes left. Trying less strict filter...
[  8842.043] (II) VESA(0): SME2220NW: Using hsync range of 30.00-81.00 kHz
[  8842.043] (II) VESA(0): SME2220NW: Using vrefresh range of 56.00-75.00 Hz
[  8842.043] (WW) VESA(0): Unable to estimate virtual size
[  8842.043] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "1920x1440" (hsync out of range)
[  8842.043] (--) VESA(0): Virtual size is 1600x1200 (pitch 1600)
[  8842.043] (**) VESA(0): *Built-in mode "1600x1200"
[  8842.043] (**) VESA(0): *Built-in mode "1280x1024"
[  8842.043] (**) VESA(0): *Built-in mode "1024x768"
[  8842.043] (**) VESA(0): *Built-in mode "1024x768"
[  8842.043] (**) VESA(0): *Built-in mode "800x600"
[  8842.043] (**) VESA(0): *Built-in mode "640x480"
[  8842.043] (==) VESA(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[  8842.043] (II) VESA(0): Attempting to use 65Hz refresh for mode "1600x1200" (15a)
[  8842.044] (II) VESA(0): Attempting to use 75Hz refresh for mode "1280x1024" (11b)
[  8842.044] (II) VESA(0): Attempting to use 75Hz refresh for mode "1024x768" (118)
[  8842.044] (II) VESA(0): Attempting to use 75Hz refresh for mode "1024x768" (17f)
[  8842.044] (II) VESA(0): Attempting to use 72Hz refresh for mode "800x600" (115)
[  8842.044] (II) VESA(0): Attempting to use 73Hz refresh for mode "640x480" (112)
[  8842.045] (**) VESA(0): Using "Shadow Framebuffer"
[  8842.045] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[  8842.045] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[  8842.045] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[  8842.045] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  8842.045]    compiled for 1.13.1.901, module version = 1.1.0
[  8842.045]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  8842.045] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[  8842.045] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[  8842.045] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[  8842.045] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  8842.045]    compiled for 1.13.1.901, module version = 1.0.0
[  8842.045]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  8842.045] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[  8842.045] (II) Unloading modesetting
[  8842.045] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[  8842.045] (II) Unloading fbdev
[  8842.045] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[  8842.045] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[  8842.045] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[  8842.045] (II) Loading sub module "int10"
[  8842.045] (II) LoadModule: "int10"
[  8842.045] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libint10.so
[  8842.045] (II) Module int10: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  8842.045]    compiled for 1.13.1.901, module version = 1.0.0
[  8842.045]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 13.1
[  8842.045] (II) VESA(0): initializing int10
[  8842.045] (II) VESA(0): Primary V_BIOS segment is: 0xc000
[  8842.045] (II) VESA(0): VESA BIOS detected
[  8842.045] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Version 3.0
[  8842.045] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Total Mem: 262080 kB
[  8842.045] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM: Intel(R) Sandybridge/Ivybridge Graphics Chipset Accelerated VGA BIOS
[  8842.045] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Software Rev: 1.0
[  8842.045] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Vendor: Intel Corporation
[  8842.045] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product: Intel(R) Sandybridge/Ivybridge Graphics Controller
[  8842.045] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product Rev: Hardware Version 0.0
[  8842.048] (II) VESA(0): virtual address = 0x7ff66b6ab000,
    physical address = 0xe0000000, size = 268369920
[  8842.054] (II) VESA(0): Setting up VESA Mode 0x15A (1600x1200)
[  8842.126] (==) VESA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[  8842.126] (==) VESA(0): Backing store disabled
[  8842.127] (==) VESA(0): DPMS enabled
[  8842.127] (WW) VESA(0): Option "ConnectedMonitor" is not used
[  8842.127] (WW) VESA(0): Option "CustomEDID" is not used
[  8842.127] (WW) VESA(0): Option "enable" is not used
[  8842.127] (WW) VESA(0): Option "Preferred Mode" is not used
[  8842.127] (WW) VESA(0): Option "TwinView" is not used
[  8842.127] (WW) VESA(0): Option "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" is not used
[  8842.127] (WW) VESA(0): Option "metamodes" is not used
[  8842.127] (==) RandR enabled
[  8842.129] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[  8842.129] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI capable
[  8842.133] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[  8842.133] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
[  8842.149] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[  8842.150] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[  8842.150] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  8842.150] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[  8842.150] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[  8842.150] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  8842.150]    compiled for 1.13.0, module version = 2.7.3
[  8842.150]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[  8842.150]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 18.0
[  8842.150] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[  8842.150] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[  8842.150] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[  8842.150] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[  8842.150] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[  8842.150] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[  8842.150] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1/event1"
[  8842.150] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[  8842.150] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[  8842.150] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  8842.150] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  8842.150] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[  8842.150] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  8842.150] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[  8842.150] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[  8842.150] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[  8842.150] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[  8842.150] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[  8842.150] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[  8842.150] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event0"
[  8842.150] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[  8842.150] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[  8842.150] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  8842.150] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  8842.150] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event3)
[  8842.150] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  8842.150] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  8842.151] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line (/dev/input/event4)
[  8842.151] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  8842.151] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  8842.151] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Mic (/dev/input/event5)
[  8842.151] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  8842.151] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  8842.151] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic (/dev/input/event6)
[  8842.151] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  8842.151] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  8842.151] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone (/dev/input/event7)
[  8842.151] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  8842.151] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  8842.151] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line Out (/dev/input/event8)
[  8842.151] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[  8842.151] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[  8842.151] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Eee PC WMI hotkeys (/dev/input/event2)
[  8842.151] (**) Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  8842.151] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Eee PC WMI hotkeys'
[  8842.151] (**) Eee PC WMI hotkeys: always reports core events
[  8842.151] (**) evdev: Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[  8842.151] (--) evdev: Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Vendor 0 Product 0
[  8842.151] (--) evdev: Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Found keys
[  8842.151] (II) evdev: Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Configuring as keyboard
[  8842.151] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/eeepc-wmi/input/input2/event2"
[  8842.151] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Eee PC WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[  8842.151] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[  8842.151] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  8842.151] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
```

Comment: How did you generate the Xorg.conf file ? Isn't there a similar problem with the keyboard and mouse ? My Xubuntu 12.04 LTS desktop used as server is connected to a KVM and often reboots without connected to the Display, keyboard and mouse. When Intel driver starts it doesn't see a connected Display and it falls back to vesa driver.

Answer (score 5):

There is an easier way to do this if you are going to go headless only: Don't use a standard X server.

I do this fairly often on boxes that almost never have monitors attached. This example uses xdm on debian, but I have done it with kdm and gdm.

specify Xvnc as the X server to use with its full path and specify the resolution on the command line. for example here is one of my /etc/X11/xdm/Xservers from a headless box.

```
:0 local /usr/bin/Xvnc :0 -nolisten tcp -desktop crystal:0 -geometry 1400x1050 -rfbauth /home/ben/.vnc/passwd
```

and just to make things nicer I created /etc/X11/Xsession-0

```
#!/bin/sh
#

vncconfig -nowin &
# invoke global X session script
. /etc/X11/Xsession
```

and add to /etc/X11/xdm/xdm-config the following line

```
DisplayManager._0.session:      /etc/X11/Xsession-0
```

to automatically start vncconfig on (and only on) all known Xvnc instances. On mixed local remote setups I use two X servers, one traditional one virtual. works like a charm. this unfortunately is more difficult on the current ultra user-friendly display managers because they try too hard to make things easy.

Comment: +1 for _more difficult on the current ultra user-friendly display managers because they try too hard to make things easy_ (and answer)

Comment: following your answer, sill i recieve `failed to load gnome-classic` on vncsession. literally I have only a terminal windows and thats all.

Comment: @Amir I don't play with gome much anymore, so i can't give you detailed help, but I do know some versions require hardware accelerated graphics which vnc does not normally provide. turbovnc documentation may be of some help but you may also want to ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Using `xrandr` you can define new modelines. This line is from my `~/.xinitrc` it runs every time an X session starts. This explicitly defines a 1280x720 60Hz mode that can be applied to any output.

`xrandr --newmode "1280x720p" 74.25 1280 1320 1376 1650 720 722 728 750`

Then apply it with (also can be applied via `.xinitrc` for ever session automatically):

```
xrandr --addmode HDMI1 "1280x720p"
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode "1280x720p"
```

Of course change the `HDMI1` to your actual output. It works even if the output has no display connected.

Comment: WIthout an Xorg configuration file, xrandr screen dimension configuration doesn't work because the Intel driver gives up if no connected display is found and the vesa driver is started instead without KMS support. In this case the last xrandr command fails with a CRT 0 error. If the vesa driver is started without KMS support and xrandr -q is executed, the output is named *default* instead of VGA1, HDM1 or whatever. This is a quicker way to diagnose this situation than scanning the log /etc/var/Xorg.0.log file.

Comment: At least on my Ubuntu 14.04, the intel driver starts even when the screen is disconnected. However, i had a hard time finding a modeline that worked with my monitor and video card. Connect the monitor, boot, and use `xrandr --verbose` to get the name of the output and a working mode line.