# How to force X to use specific display, regardless if it is plugged in?

Tags: xorg, x11, monitors, hdmi

As it says in title:

How to force xorg to use specific display trough HDMI, regardless if it is plugged in?

I have TV that has some crazy "power save" option that can't be turned off and X thinks that HDMI is unplugged. After that, everything goes mad and sometimes my program bricks.

If I could tell X to act as there is always that TV plugged in into HDMI that would solve problem.

Answer (score 1):

See if [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63216/how-to-configure-xorg-conf-for-widescreen-vnc-on-headless-linux-ubuntu) post helps you at all or if it can give you some ideas about the things involved with configuring your display.  Also, look at the different options that '[xrandr](http://www.x.org/wiki/Projects/XRandR)' and '[EDID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EDID)' allow.