# Headlessly Compiling and Uploading Arduino Programs on an armhf Platform

Tags: debian, arm, headless, arduino

I'm currently running my Hardkernel ODROID U2 with the ODUINO One (Arduino Uno R3 & additions) in a headless setup and connect to the ODROID U2 via SSH over LAN.
It is running Debian 7.1 armhf and got all major libraries that are needed to compile software, but no X-Server is installed.

When I try to start the Arduino work environment via the console command `arduino`, it spits out a Java exception telling me that I don't have an X-Display.

How would I headlessly compile and upload Arduino programs if not through the `arduino` command?

Comment: how annoying! does your jre have a headless version? hav you tried X forwarding over ssh? If those don't work my answer http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63216/how-to-configure-xorg-conf-for-widescreen-vnc-on-headless-linux-ubuntu/106448#106448 will provide a way to run a xserver on a headless box.

Answer (score 3):

Some Java libraries require an X server as part of their initialization code, whether the program ends up using it or not.

If you need an X server just for the sake of having one, you can use [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb), which is X server with a virtual framebuffer, i.e. an X server that displays only in memory and doesn't connect to any hardware.

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1x1x8 &
```

You need to wait a little after starting Xvfb for the display to be available. In a script, you can tell the X server to start some program when it's ready.

```
mkfifo ready
xinit /bin/sh -c 'echo >ready; exec sleep 99999999' -- /usr/bin/Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1x1x8 &
read ready
export DISPLAY=:1
…
```

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino IDE is GUI only. It can not be ran from a command line alone. To begin with check out [PlayGround](http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/CommandLine). Basically you need to compile from a make file, as an alternative to the IDE's GUI. There are plenty of other resources out there on this.

Answer (score 0):

http://robokitchen.tumblr.com/post/98340595745/arduino-continuous-integration contains a section called "Arduino IDE headless" which describes what you are trying to achieve but on Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS.