# Unable to increase the screen resolution on headless Fedora after upgrade (25)

Tags: linux, fedora, xrandr, resolution

I have a headless Linux machine which I run as a “mini-server” at home and is installed with Fedora 24 server with LXDE desktop. Two days ago, I connected it to a monitor and upgraded it to Fedora 25. Installation went fine; however, whenever I tried to login, it used to log me out at the first mouse click. I was not able to login through GUI whatsoever (however, I was able to login via terminal).

Upon going through 100s of blogs and 100s of trial and error, I found out that long ago I had a setup in `.bash_profile` to increase the resolution whenever I connect using TeamViewer (as this server is headless almost all the time and I use the machine’s GUI only though TeamViewer). This was the culprit. After removing this, I was able to login without a problem. Now I don’t know how to increase the resolution when I connect to the headless server via TeamViewer. I was using the below command to set the resolution from Fedora 21 until 24:

```
xrandr –newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr –addmode VIRTUAL1 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr –output VIRTUAL1 –mode 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr –output LVDS1 –off
```

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your problem, but: you don't need to have ``1920x1080_60.00`` in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases (all except one I'll mention in a moment) the RandR framework talks to the monitor. The reason for this is to have the monitor always readable, and so most tools actively work against what you are trying to do.

The exception is framebuffers not associated with a real monitor including Xvfb, Xvnc, Xnest and the poorly documented and possibly unsupported virtual device you found. (I suspect it had a name change or got removed.)

Now since you say you do not use the GUI locally might I suggest that since you are not using the monitor you might not need a video card. [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63216/how-to-configure-xorg-conf-for-widescreen-vnc-on-headless-linux-ubuntu/106448#106448) I document a simplified version of my setup, and with tigervnc's resize ability the desktop is always the right size. I have been using this setup since the early nineties, but now I don't specify a resolution, I just resize.